# Attic Ventilation Help

Tags: roof, attic, ventilation, soffit

Looking for some guidance. I've read through several other posts on this topic, but would like to get some insight on our specific situation. Any constructive advice is appreciated.

We're finishing the attic in our 1920s 1.5 story bungalow. The attic was previously unfinished and had a few cap vents along the north side. We covered the cap vents, cut in a ridge vent, drilled ventilation holes along the blocking between the rafters on the soffit side, installed venting chutes, and insulated (fiberglass batt and then rigid foam). The soffits are wrapped and appeared to have a few vent panels interspersed. **We are currently finding wet insulation/ condensation where the rafters meet the exterior walls, primarily on the north side.** All we can figure is that there is not enough ventilation in the soffit panels to draw the air from the soffit to the ridge vent, which is causing condensation to build up and run downhill and collect at the bottom. I should mention that we have had little/ no snow this year, so it is not an ice dam issue.

Here are the specifics of our house that may/ may not be helpful:

- 1927 1.5 story, stucco
- Minneapolis, MN
- 2x4 24" OC rafters
- 6/12 roof pitch, gable roof
- Ridge runs east/ west
- 3" x 33' ridge vent
- (3) 1" holes drilled in the blocking of each rafter bay to allow air in from soffits
- R13 paper faced insulation (paper facing interior of space) between rafters
- 1" R6 foil-faced polyiso foam board on top of batt insulation (facing interior of space)

Thanks, all!

[image: drilled holes in blocking]

[image: vent chutes, batt insulation]

[image: polyiso insulation]

[image: soffit exterior]

[image: soffit interior]

[image: exterior side of drilled holes in blocking]

[image: moisture buildup]

Comment: I would expect the soffits to have every second section to be perforated, not one every three or more sections.   Can you see daylight from the holes you drilled?

Comment: The second image shows blocking that interrupts a rafter cavity. I assume that all of these locations have been punctured analogous to the exterior wall blocking, yeah?

Comment: The vapor retarder should prevent warm moist air from even getting up there. I think the gap filling spray foam stuff is technically rated as air permeable, so any edges where the foil faced polyiso meet should be taped. A side wall outlet for a dryer or a gas fireplace could be the source of warm, moist air that enters the rafter cavities through the soffit. A roof leak or leak at the ridge vent are candidate moisture sources.

Comment: Do you get snow?  Sometimes blowing snow can get though ridge vents if not done right.  A bit of snow melts but not a roof leak when raining.

Comment: Thanks @popham, and good eye on the blocking. Yes, holes have been added into any blocking. We have one exhaust vent on each side of the house, so with the uniform condensation across the length of the soffits, I’m not sure those vents are the culprit. Thanks again

Comment: @crip659 thanks. The soffit panels are almost entirely solid. We do get snow but none this winter (odd weather), so can’t blame it on that

Comment: The soffits will be about the easiest and cheapest to change.  You should be able to see daylight/some light from most of those 1 inch holes you drilled.  No light, probably little air movement.  I am assuming those soffit panels about 4 or 6 inches wide or more before the next open section.

Comment: You mean you found the moisture concentrated at one location, but you anticipate two vents having the same moisture output rates with the moisture uniformly distributed across the soffit? Or the moisture is uniformly distributed across many rafter cavities?

Comment: @popham the moisture is uniformly spread across all of the rafter cavities. The vents are not the culprits

Comment: Thanks @crip659. That’s my plan: drill out more holes in the blocking, swap out the soffit covers with a vented version.

Comment: Your foil faced insulation has a 0.05 perm rating or less. A commercial steam shower calls for a rating of 0.5. With proper taping, interior moisture shouldn't be the source of your problem. It probably isn't even without proper taping.